# How to extend/override mvc html.LabelFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an overload for `LabelFor` that can be used like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(i => i.MyProperty)
```

How can I get the compiler to use my overload instead of the one provided by MVC ootb?

Basically this is just so that I can have required fields label's spit out with * suffix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that overload, you can't (reasonably).

Just name the method `Label()` or `MyLabelFor()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`LabelFor` accepts an `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>` parameter. I would imagine you *could* do something like:

```
public static string LabelFor<TModel, string>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmLHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, string>> expression) {
    // etc
```

... to make your extension method overload more *specific*, but that doesn't mean you *should*, as you would need to do so for *all* property types.

Rather than have your method naming get mixed up with the standard `HtmlHelper` extension methods, name it differently, e.g.

```
@Html.MyLabelFor(m => m.MyProperty);
```

Comment: Your LabelFor should result in a run time binding exception for not being able to resolve between MVC built in and your extension method. You would need to remove the MVC built in namespace from the extensions section in the web.config which would become an extreme pain point. This is why I said you can't reasonably create that overload.